# do we a shorthand to get a count of number of rows are present in db with respect to a where clause in r2bc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

"Is there any short hand to **no .of rows in a database against a where condition**"
if we have a criteria definition present against which  want number of rows present in database. **is is any function in r2dbc that give that?**

Comment: As it is about executing SQL, what is wrong with doing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE <YOUR-CONDITION>` why would that be different here?

Comment: The condition that gets build up is dynamic, it depends on fields that are populated in my object of criteria definition

Comment: So? What prevents you from executing a dynamic query? If you can execute a query you can also execute the count query.

Comment: How can we create a query from CriteriaObject the method execute() requires a string

Comment: like we have select(), insert() methods in r2dbc so do we have a method for count as well

Comment: what do you think `select` does. How is a `select count(*)` different from `select foo, bar from baz`. It is just a select statement.

Comment: @DEVYANISETHI It's been quite a while since you asked this question. Any updates from your side? Did you try out the answer I had provided?

Answer (score 2):

You can have something like this:

```
@Repository
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl {

  private final R2dbcEntityTemplate r2dbcEntityTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public MyCustomRepositoryImpl(DatabaseClient databaseClient) {
    this.r2dbcEntityTemplate = new R2dbcEntityTemplate(databaseClient);
  }

  public Mono<Long> getCountOfAllRows() {
    return r2dbcEntityTemplate.count(query(Criteria.empty()),MyEntity.class);
  }

  public Mono<Long> getCountOfRowsForACondition(String myVal) {
    return r2dbcEntityTemplate.select(query(Criteria.where("mycolumn").is(myVal)),MyEntity.class);
  }
}
```

Note here `query` is the static method of `org.springframework.data.relational.core.query.Query`